# how to disable user from exit page, inside OnDisappearing method?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

how to disable user from exit page?

here await doesnt work. it just goes back to previous page and than display message

```
 protected async override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            var answer = await DisplayAlert("Changes un-saved", 
                "You must tap on 'save' button", "Exit", "Stay on this page");
            if (!answer || String.Compare(answer.ToString(), "Exit") == 0)
               base.OnDisappearing();
            else if(string.Compare(answer.ToString(), "Stay on this page") == 0)
             //here i want to stay on same page
        }
```

I tried this but i dont want page to load

```
      var route = $"//{ nameof(EditPage)}";
     await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
```

I also tried this, but onbackbuttonpress only works if user hit back button on mobile. not back button in app

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        bool myResult = PromptForExit().Result;
        if (myResult)
            return true; // dont go back 
        return false;
    }
    private async Task<bool> PromptForExit()
    {
        var answer = await DisplayAlert("Changes un-saved",
        "You must tap on 'save' button",
        "Exit",
        "Stay on this page");
        if (string.Compare(answer.ToString(), "Stay on this page") == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Have you created an custom back button? As pressing back button of app also fire `OnBackButtonPressed`... And are you testing on android or iOS?

Comment: `OnBackButtonPressed` have some issues with iOS for not getting fired, you have to extend the page to do so

Comment: no i am using android default back button which gets created by using `GoToAsync` in android

Comment: Try the answer i posted & let me know if that worked for you or not.

Comment: Have you tried and solved your problem with one of the below answers or with your own solution or not yet? please update.

Answer (score 0):

Set the attached property `Shell.PresentationMode` in the page you want to restrict use to stay on it this will show the page as a modal page  (navigation bar will be hidden..), and at the same time override the back button like you did, but be sure to allow navigation out of that page somehow if required, thru a button on that page for example that calls `Shell.GotoAsync("..")`

```
<ContentPage ...
Shell.PresentationMode="ModalAnimated"
```

You may also set it value to `Modal` or `ModalNotAnimated`.

**Docs** [Shell presentation mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/pages#set-page-presentation-mode)

Comment: Please let me know if that approach works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() => {
            bool myResult = await PromptForExit();

            if (myResult) await this.Navigation.PopAsync();
        });

        return true;
    }
```

Let me know if it work for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question since Apple is determined to state that the "back" action must not be interrupted by the application. You can interrupt the android hardware backbutton, you can just yet interrupt the `NavigationPage` software backbutton, but you cannot in any way interrupt the `MasterDetailPage` software backbutton.

Used to, if you want to prevent the user from going back, you had to use something like this:

```
var loginPage = new LoginPage();
var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(loginPage);
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(loginPage, true);
// Disable the back button
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(loginPage, false);
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(navigationPage);
```

The recommended way of interacting with the "back" action was to use a modal page using `Navigation.PushModalAsync()`. It's a lot less painful.

Have you already tried using the new [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#back-button-behavior). Microsoft introduced it last year just for this reason.

This seems to be an interesting investigation into the Shell: https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2020/06/09/overriding-back-button-in-xamarin-forms-shell/